# rhdfs library doesn't work

Tags: r, cloudera, rhadoop

i'm trying to use hadoop with R into a cloudera VM.
i load rhdfs library into R and goes fine but when i try to execute hdfs.init() , this doesn't work and give me the following error:

```
> hdfs.init()
14/12/10 05:48:20 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: Unable to find JAAS    classes:com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal 
not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rJava/java/boot/],
parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
14/12/10 05:48:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for 
your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
java.io.IOException: failure to login
```

This is my code:

> Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
>   Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.2.0.jar")
>   Sys.setenv("HADOOP_HOME"="/usr/lib/hadoop")
>   Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CONF_DIR"="/etc/hadoop/conf")
>
> library(rhdfs)
>   Loading required package: rJava
>
> HADOOP_CMD=/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop
>
> Be sure to run hdfs.init()
>   hdfs.init()
>   14/12/11 05:55:21 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: Unable to find JAAS classes:com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rJava/java/boot/], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
>   14/12/11 05:55:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
>     java.io.IOException: failure to login

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Check that your IDE picks up the correct environment variables, by using `Sys.Getenv()`

Comment: yes i put the full code and vars settings directly into R

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue running RStudio with sudo and then reloading tar.gz of hrdfs and rmr and then when executing rhdfs.init() i get this message:

```
> hdfs.init()
14/12/15 10:29:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for    your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>
```

sholud be ok